# Spring rest template post xml - error No HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot(2.7.6) rest application that should call a POST endpoint which contains the following request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <folder>
    <created>2022-12-02T10:30:18.673Z</created>
    <path>/okm:root/test3</path>
  </folder>
```

In order to call the endpoints I have created the following method:

```
    @SneakyThrows
    @GetMapping("/create")
    public void post() {



        MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

        body.add("path", "/okm:root/test4");

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.ALL.getType());
        headers.setBasicAuth("dummy", "admin");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);


        // Note the body object as first parameter!
        HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, headers);

        ResponseEntity<Folder> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/OpenKM/services/rest/folder/create", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Folder.class);

        System.out.println(response);

    }
```

The pom.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.service.openmk</groupId>
    <artifactId>openmk-service-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>openmk-service-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
      <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>openkm.com</id>
            <name>OpenKM Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.openkm.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openkm</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

However when i call the method above the following exception is triggered:

```
2022-12-02 15:19:37.906 ERROR 14044 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap and content type "application/xml"] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap and content type "application/xml"
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:1006) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
```

Can someone please help me out to fix the above error?

Comment: please also provide your `pom.xml` dependencies

Comment: @Rustam I have added pom file content

Comment: Write a proper object that can be converted to XML. You cannot shove a Map in there and expect it magically to generate XML. XML is more complex then JSON and thus needs additional information. For this use an objct with XML mapping annotations so that the XML generator (generally JAXB but you could jackson as well) knows what to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

1. ensure that `spring.xml.ignore` is true (by default it is true)
   you can check in you controller by calling
   `SpringProperties.getFlag("spring.xml.ignore")`
2. The main problem: there are no any built in impl of `HttpMessageConverter` for  `application/xml` in spring-web (without additional dependencies). However Spring can parse and build xml body/response using JAXB or jackson lib. For this purpose Spring check 2 classes for availability from ClassLoader:
   `javax.xml.bind.Binder` (impl in `jaxb-api`) and
   `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` (part of `jackson-dataformat-xml`)
   I prefer to use `jackson-dataformat-xml`, due to huge developers community of jackson libs. Shortly said solution is to add dependency to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```